# How to Extract SAP-PASSPORT to send it to the new request in JMeter | SAP Fiori

Tags: performance, jmeter, extract, sap-fiori

Is there any way to pass or store SAP-PASSPORT to next request in JMeter?

Currently it's coming as `Referrer` under HTTP Header of the Request (SAP Fiori) (edited).

Note: I am preparing scripts to do a performance testing on SAP Fiori Apps.

I have tried extractors but not able to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a suitable [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) i.e. [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor), example configuration would be something like:

[image]

Textual representation of the regular expression:

```
SAP-PASSPORT\s*?:\s*?(.*)
```

where:

- `\` - escape character
- `\s` - whitespace character
- `?` - means that the character is optional (may or may not present)
- `.` - matches any character
- `*` - repetition
  -`()` - grouping

More information:

- [JMeter: Regular Expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)